# Como pillo determinada parte de un string en python

Tags: python, regex

Digamos que tengo un string como el siguiente:

```
Stats name=WebContainer, type=threadPoolModule
{
name=ActiveCount, ID=3, description=The number of concurrently active threads., unit=N/A, type=BoundedRangeStatistic, lowWaterMark=0, highWaterMark=0, current=0, integral=0.0, lowerBound=0, upperBound=0

name=PoolSize, ID=4, description=The average number of threads in a pool., unit=N/A, type=BoundedRangeStatistic, lowWaterMark=50, highWaterMark=50, current=0, integral=0.0, lowerBound=50, upperBound=50

name=DeclaredThreadHungCount, ID=6, description=The number of threads that are declared stopped., unit=N/A, type=CountStatistic, count=0

name=ClearedThreadHangCount, ID=7, description=The number of thread stops that cleared., unit=N/A, type=CountStatistic, count=0

name=ConcurrentHungThreadCount, ID=8, description=The number of concurrently stopped threads., unit=N/A, type=RangeStatistic, lowWaterMark=0, highWaterMark=0, current=0, integral=0.0
}
```

A mi me interesa pillar el dato de current de ActiveCount y de PoolSize (pillar el 0 solo)

Por ejemplo, tener una variable con el valor de current de active count y otra con el valor de current de poolsize.

como podría hacerlo en python?

Comment: Hola @alejandro, deberías poner qué has intentado primero

Comment: si todo eso es un string pues creo que no has escogido correctamente la estructura de dato

Answer (score 2):

Esa cadena ¿te viene dada o es un formato que has elegido tú? Lo pregunto porque como formato es horrible, pues no es posible por ejemplo que el campo "description" contenga comas, pues eso haría muy difícil saber si esa coma pertenece a la descripción o es un separador con el campo siguiente. Tampoco me parece buena elección el "fin de línea" como delimitador de registros.

En realidad, la estructura más apropiada para la información que almacena esa cadena sería un JSON o un YAML.

Pero en fin, supongamos que la cadena te viene dada y no hay más remedio que adaptarse a ella. Lo primero que haría sería procesarla para convertirla en una lista de diccionarios:

```
def convertir_a_lista_de_diccionarios(cadena):
  lista = []
  for linea in cadena.split("\n"):
    if "description" not in linea:
      continue
    d = {}
    for trozo in linea.split(","):
      clave, valor = trozo.strip().split("=")
      d[clave]=valor
    lista.append(d)
  return lista
```

aquí, el *heuristico* es dividir la cadena por los retornos de carro, saltarse todas las líneas que no contengan la palabra "description" (para así saltarse la cabecera, la apertura de llaves y su cierre y las líneas en blanco) y las restantes dividirlas por la coma, para cada uno de los trozos volver a dividirlo por el signo = y así obtener la pareja (clave, valor) con la que construir los diccionarios.

El resultado de llamar a esta función sobre tu cadena sería:

```
[{'ID': '3',
  'current': '0',
  'description': 'The number of concurrently active threads.',
  'highWaterMark': '0',
  'integral': '0.0',
  'lowWaterMark': '0',
  'lowerBound': '0',
  'name': 'ActiveCount',
  'type': 'BoundedRangeStatistic',
  'unit': 'N/A',
  'upperBound': '0'},
 {'ID': '4',
  'current': '0',
  'description': 'The average number of threads in a pool.',
  'highWaterMark': '50',
  'integral': '0.0',
  'lowWaterMark': '50',
  'lowerBound': '50',
  'name': 'PoolSize',
  'type': 'BoundedRangeStatistic',
  'unit': 'N/A',
  'upperBound': '50'},
 {'ID': '6',
  'count': '0',
  'description': 'The number of threads that are declared stopped.',
  'name': 'DeclaredThreadHungCount',
  'type': 'CountStatistic',
  'unit': 'N/A'},
 {'ID': '7',
  'count': '0',
  'description': 'The number of thread stops that cleared.',
  'name': 'ClearedThreadHangCount',
  'type': 'CountStatistic',
  'unit': 'N/A'},
 {'ID': '8',
  'current': '0',
  'description': 'The number of concurrently stopped threads.',
  'highWaterMark': '0',
  'integral': '0.0',
  'lowWaterMark': '0',
  'name': 'ConcurrentHungThreadCount',
  'type': 'RangeStatistic',
  'unit': 'N/A'}]
```

Esto ya es mucho más sencillo de procesar. En concreto basta iterar por la lista y comparar el `"name"` con el caso que te interesa, para después sacar el dato `"current"`:

```
datos = convertir_a_lista_de_diccionarios(cadena)
for d in datos:
  for busco in ["ActiveCount", "PoolSize"]:
    if d["name"] == busco:
      current = d["current"]
      print(f"{busco} current={current}")
```

Resultado de la ejecución:

```
ActiveCount current=0
PoolSize current=0
```

## Otra posibilidad

Muy similar a la anterior, pero en lugar de tener los datos en una lista, tenerlos en otro diccionario cuya clave sea el "name". Eso evitará tener que iterar más tarde por la lista para encontrar el nombre adecuado.

En este caso la función que procesa los datos va añadiendo entradas a ese "diccionario de diccionarios". Las claves serían los nombres, y los valores los mismos diccionarios que había en la lista de la solución anterior.

Sería así:

```
def convertir_a_diccionario_de_diccionarios(cadena):
  dicc = {}
  for linea in cadena.split("\n"):
    if "description" not in linea:
      continue
    d = {}
    for trozo in linea.split(","):
      clave, valor = trozo.strip().split("=")
      d[clave]=valor
    dicc[d["name"]] = d
  return dicc
```

Y en este caso encontrar la información buscada es mucho más simple:

```
datos = convertir_a_diccionario_de_diccionarios(cadena)
print(datos["ActiveCount"]["current"])
print(datos["PoolSize"]["current"])
```

Resultado:

```
0
0
```

Comment: Hay preguntas que no merecen respuestas.